# MonoTouch: Application windows are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch

Tags: xcode, xamarin.ios

### Please note, unlike similar questions in the past, this issue is for IOS 6 and I am not calling window.AddSubview (navigation.View) which was documented in past answers.

When I launch my app in the simulator it opens and the message below is displayed in the Application Output window.  I am running: Monotouch: 6.0.10, xcode 4.6

> Application windows are expected to have a root view controller at the
>   end of application launch

```
    [Register ("AppDelegate")]
public partial class AppDelegate : UIApplicationDelegate
{
    UIWindow window;
    ProductXchangeViewController viewController;
    public override bool FinishedLaunching (UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
    {
        window = new UIWindow (UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds);         
        viewController = new ProductXchangeViewController ();
        window.RootViewController = viewController;
        window.MakeKeyAndVisible ();
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: Is there any additional trace available? I'm not sure whoever voted to close is correct - your codes does look like it is setting the RootViewController - so this is not a duplicate (IMO)

Comment: I've read the previous questions like the link that was added above but these all address earlier versions of IOS and perhaps the person that added this link did not see that I use RootViewController and not the subView...  It was not a crash so I do not have a stack trace.  It   appears to exit with this message.

Comment: The only things I can think to suggest right now are: 1. Add some trace and some breakpoints to FIinishedLaunching - what gets called? 2. What happens if you use a new blank UIViewController - does the app start OK then?

Comment: I quickly tried to create an empty UIViewController and (due to a segv stack trace) it looks like the call to the base class constructor for the UIViewController is trying to load the NIB (xib?) file or some object within.  Could I have some inconsistency between my xib file and what I see in the interface builder/header file in Xcode?

Comment: Does a File|new iPhone project work OK in your setup? If it does then something is wrong in this current project... can't really help work out what that is from here!

Comment: I think something is wrong in my current project.  In my learning curve I have been trying to understand Xcode and creating outlets and actions...  I have deleted entries in the header file when trying different approaches.  Editing this file should not cause problems, correct? This why I question the contents of the xib file vs what I see in the interface builder.  I can create a new project for now but I don't want to run into this when bigger projects are underway!  Thanks for looking at this @Stuart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I re-implmented my user interface in a new UIViewController xib and did not change FinishedLaunching() or any other code and it worked.

XCode must have introduced a problem in the xib file.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure this completes in a timely manner? You have iirc 17 seconds to return from FinishedLunching.